# Lenguaje C: No se ejecuta mi programa despues del "scanf"

Tags: c

recién estoy aprendiendo C y no entiendo porque no se ejecuta nada de lo que escribo debajo del scanf. Probe imprimiendo cosas que no requerian variables ni nada e igual no se ejecuta :c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main (){
    int ORDEN_L, i, j; 
    
    printf("Ejercicio 61: Hacer un programa en SL que encuentre el mayor y el menor elemento del triangulo superior de una matriz M de orden L. \n"); 
    printf("Ingrese el orden de la matriz:  ") ; 
    scanf("%d", ORDEN_L); 
    
    int M [ORDEN_L][ORDEN_L]; 
    
    // Carga de la matriz con random 
    for (i=0; i<ORDEN_L; i++){
        for (j=0; j<ORDEN_L; j++){ 
        M[i][j]= rand() % 100; 
        
    }; }; 
    
    // Impresión de la matriz 
        for (i=1; i<=ORDEN_L; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=ORDEN_L; j++){ 
        printf("%d \t", M[i][j]); 
        
    }; 
        printf("\n"); 
    }; 
    
    // Se busca el mayor y menor elemento 
    int mayor = 0; int menor = 110; 
    
    for (i=1; i<=ORDEN_L; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=ORDEN_L; j++){ 
            if ((j>i)&&(M[i][j]<menor)){
                menor=M[i][j]; 
            }; 
            if ((j>i)&&(M[i][j]>mayor)){
                mayor=M[i][j]; 
            }
        
    }; }; 
return 0; 
}
```

Agradeceria que me corrijan cualquier otro error en la sintaxis o logica ya que no pude ejecutar mi programa ni una vez u.u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` tiene que recibir un puntero para poder modificar el valor de tu variable. Tienes que usar `&` para obtener la dirección de memoria de la variable:

```
scanf("%d", &ORDEN_L);
//          ^
```